# Razor bind radiobox to list of SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a basic model

```
public class SpeakerConsent
{
    public string FieldLabel { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> OptionValues { get; set; }
}
```

My razor page currently looks like the following

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.OptionValues.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.OptionValues[i].Selected, Model.OptionValues[i].Value )
}
```

I might have 4 or 5 items in my OptionValues.

Question : How can i bind to the Selected property of the SelectListItem so when the model is posted i can identify which on of the radio buttons has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, the HTML markup generated for the input element will be like below

```
<input data-val="true" name="OptionValues[0].Selected" type="radio" value="201">
```

the name is `Selected` and the value is a number. The `Selected` property of the `SelectListItem` is `bool` type. Model binding will not work as expected when you post this form data.

IMHO, The easiest way to handle a scenario like this is to use editor templates.

I will first create a class which represents the data I want to use with the radio buttons.

```
public class MyOption
{
    public bool IsSelected { set; get; }
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Text { set; get; }
}
```

Now in my main view model, I will add a collection type property

```
public class SpeakerConsent
{
    public List<MyOption> Options { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your `~/Views/Shared/` directory, create a folder called `EditorTemplates` and then create a view called `MyOption.cshtml` in that. You can have the HTML markup you want to use to render the radio button in that. Here I am keeping the `Id` property in a hidden field along with the radio button and label.

```
@model YourNamespace.MyOption
<div>
    <span>@Model.Text</span>
    @Html.HiddenFor(g=>g.Id)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.IsSelected, true)
</div>
```

Now in your GET action, you can populate this `Options` property of yout `SpeakerConsent` view model object and send to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm = new SpeakerConsent();
   vm.Options = new List<MyOption>
   {
       new MyOption { Id=1, Text="Seattle"},
       new MyOption { Id=2, Text="Detroit"},
       new MyOption { Id=31, Text="Kerala"},
   };
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your main view, you can simply call the `EditorFor` helper method.

```
@model YourNamespace.SpeakerConsent

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(a=>a.Options)
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

> Make sure to check the HTML markup generated by this code. notice the
>   `name` attribute value of the inputs.

When the form is submitted, you can read the `Options` property value, loop through them and read the `Id` and `IsSelected` property value and use them as needed

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SpeakerConsent model)
{
   // check model.Options
   // to do : return something
}
```